# Assign python exception chain to a variable

Tags: python, exception, syntax

Usually it is possible to assign an exception to a variable and raise it later. But would that be possible for an exception chain?

For example, normally that's how we do it:

```py
default_exc = None

try:
    raise KeyError
except KeyError as exc:
    default_exc = exc

# ...

raise default_exc
```

What what if I want to reuse the exception chain?

```py
default_exc = None

try:
    raise KeyError
except KeyError as cause:
    default_exc = ValueError from cause  # doesn't work like that

# ...

raise default_exc  # will never even get here
```

So how to properly store the exception chain in a variable to mean this `default_exc = ValueError from cause`? Is it even possible in Python? If not, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Why not just save the cause in another variable?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That worked for me! I also thought about maybe there's something for it as let's say there are generators for loops that can be reused as a whole, but looks like having 2 variable is the simplest and sufficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments, you could of course store the exception and the cause in separate variables.

However, as you have more exceptions to chain together into one exception, you could wrap your `try/except` block into another `try/except` block which stores the chained exception like this:

```py
default_exc = None

try:
    try:
        raise KeyError
    except Exception as e1:
        raise e1 from default_exc
except Exception as e2:
    default_exc = e2

try:
    try:
        raise ValueError
    except Exception as e1:
        raise e1 from default_exc
except Exception as e2:
    default_exc = e2

default_exc  # chained exception
```

If you have a third exception emitted from elsewhere that you also want to chain with the other two, you would then decorate the statement that raises this exception with two `try/except` blocks in the same manner and assign the newly chained exception to `default_exc`.

The drawbacks here are that:

- it's usually a bad or not so nice practice to nest `try/except` blocks, and that
- one of the blocks is used to suppress an artificially emitted exception

So, this in essence qualifies as a workaround, if this behavior is needed/intended.